# check USB health as in windows 7 or 8 .

Tags: 12.04, usb

Hi in my college if I insert my USB pen drive on any windows 7 or 8 system then it will automatically starts scanning it and prompt us if it have any errors . like scan and fix errors .

is there any such functionality in ubuntu ?

Comment: Are you looking something like this kind from OS perspective? I guess this is a feature of Anti-Virus that you install normally on a Windows OS. If that is what you were looking then you can even check same kind feasibility from Linux Anti-Virus Programs(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus)

Comment: You ask one thing in your title and then ask another in the body, which one is it?, Do you want to know the health of the USB or do you want to check the USB with an anti-virus?.